# Yet another Dual boot issue Win7x64 and 12.10

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows-7

There are similar posts out there, but no answer that has helped me get this to work. Though I consider myself savvy, I'm newer to Linux.

System: AMD FX, Terabyte drive.

I have 3 partitions on this drive - system, backup, and unallocated.
The unallocated is for Linux, but when I start live CD/USB and get to the "DO SOMETHING ELSE" my NTFS partition does not show. It does show 1,000,000 free space. What am I doing wrong? I just formatted my Windows 7 partition and not having any luck. If more info is needed, please just ask. I'm really hoping to get this working again

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1694495/ If this helps any....

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to view your hdd with the Disks manager? If you simply cannot see your Win7 on the Grub boot menu, I have discussed some methods my blog which might help:

By using boot-fix:
http://linuxtecsun.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-fix-multi-boot-lost-of-any-os.html

Manual edit:
http://linuxtecsun.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-fix-multi-boot-fedora-gone-after.html

Below is a Win7 entry if you want to edit manually:

```
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-D4665DF6665DD9B6' {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  D4665DF6665DD9B6
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root D4665DF6665DD9B6
fi
chainloader +1
}
```

Comment: This look like a fix if both are installed already? I only have Win 7 running. Afraid to even attempt to install Ubuntu as I don't want to wipe my BACKUP partition if I can avoid it.